# How to deploy Java triggered webjob into Azure through VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-webjobs-triggered

I have webjobs runs as a Java code.All the webjobs are of type Triggered.So I wanted to deploy the triggered webjobs through VSTS.Could any one please help me out ?Please explain how to copy the webjobs as part of build and deploy into azure.Is there any script files required to deploy along with webjobs ,please explain to me.I searched google and many forums ,all explained about .net application related webjobs not for java project.So please explain how to do this.

Comment: See some reference [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/28/executing-java-web-jobs-on-azure/) and [here](https://ganeshpachpind.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/run-jar-as-azure-webjob/)

Comment: I gone through the links which you shared but through VSTS I can't deploy triggered job.Please help me. I have copied the settings.job file as per the given link and included cron expression in settings.job file and deployed along with jar file but I don't see any triggered job is running.

Comment: May be you might miss some thing. See my [answer here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/764c7776-ca87-4246-a1ea-f6253efd498b/cronscheduled-webjob-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#73262188-d93b-4d33-b780-ae2ea5eb4e2c)

Comment: I have fixed my issue by pushing settings.job file along with one batch script which will trigger webjob jar file. But if I want to create multiple webjobs in a single jar what is that procedure ?

Comment: Not having any idea about that, may be you can create a separate thread for that.since now you solved with the original question. I've converted my comments into the answer, you are welcome to accept

Answer (score 0):

Majorly the problem with triggering the webjobs will be the `setting.job` file. There are mainly 3 reasons which needs to focus to solve the problem

1. Check the JSON whether you are having any whitespaces
2. Check the Settings.job into settings.job about remove 'S' as the
   CAPS,(It's a CASE SENSITIVE)
3. Change the Copy to Output Directory to Copy Always

[image]

Which I explained [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/764c7776-ca87-4246-a1ea-f6253efd498b/cronscheduled-webjob-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview#73262188-d93b-4d33-b780-ae2ea5eb4e2c)

For deploying Java projects in webjobs you can refer [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/04/28/executing-java-web-jobs-on-azure/) and [this](https://ganeshpachpind.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/run-jar-as-azure-webjob/) links.

Comment: @ Jayendran, My issue was I need to deploy multiple triggered webjobs from VSTS to Azure. I could able to deploy triggered webjob but not sure how to deploy multiple triggered webjobs from VSTS.Please help me.